# Find and show matched substring from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me get the following output on SQL.

The table AnimalQueries contains column called OrignialString.

The OriginalString will look like below:

`with cat pain
chat to a vet online
help dog whisperer
ask vet online free
hamster treat`

I want the output to show as below

```
OriginalString           Animal
with cat pain             Cat
chat to a vet online      Vet
help dog whisperer        Dog
ask vet online free       Vet
hamster treat             Hamster
```

```
Declare @Animal table (Animal varchar(200))
insert into @Animal(Animal)
    values('dog','cat','vet','hamster')
SELECT OriginalString, Animal from AnimalQueries
```

Comment: What if there are multiple animals or no animals?

Comment: I think the first occurance should be considered incase of multiple animals and no value incase of no match

Answer (score 0):

I Think should work:

```
SELECT 
     OriginalString, 
     ( SELECT TOP(1) Animal FROM @Animal WHERE OriginalString LIKE '% ' + Animal  + ' %'  )

FROM AnimalQueries
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a join and the LIKE operator in the ON clause:

```
CREATE TABLE AnimalQueries
    ([OriginalString] varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO AnimalQueries
    ([OriginalString])
VALUES
    ('with cat pain'),
    ('chat to a vet online'),
    ('help dog whisperer'),
    ('ask vet online free'),
    ('hamster treat')
;

Declare @Animal table (Animal varchar(200))
insert into @Animal(Animal) values('dog'),('cat'),('vet'),('hamster');

select aq.OriginalString, a.Animal
from AnimalQueries aq left join @Animal a
on ' ' + aq.OriginalString + ' ' like '% ' + a.Animal + ' %'
```

By concatenating spaces before and after the `OriginalString` and `Animal` columns you can be sure that the code finds whole words in `OriginalString` and not parts of words.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d8359eb3c69c862b38e0c8551b353bb).
Results:

```
> OriginalString       | Animal 
> :------------------- | :------
> with cat pain        | cat    
> chat to a vet online | vet    
> help dog whisperer   | dog    
> ask vet online free  | vet    
> hamster treat        | hamster
```

Comment: Thanks this helps with returning blank if match type is not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM animallist A
LEFT JOIN  orginalstring O ON CHARINDEX(A.animal, O.orginalstring) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the words are separated by spaces and you want only the first match, then I would recommend:

```
select aq.*, a.animal
from animalqueries aq cross apply
     (select top (1) a.*
      from @animal a
      where ' ' + aq.originalstring + ' ' like '% ' + a.animal + ' %'
      order by charindex(' ' + a.animal + ' ', ' ' + aq.originalstring + ' ')
     ) a;
```

Note the use of the delimiters to prevent a false match on words like "scat", "rivet", "doggerel"

Comment: Any solution for if it contains no match then to shoot a blank in the output?

Comment: @VanessaPinto . . . Just use `outer apply` rather than `cross apply`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, onle last help. Is it possible to read values in Animal from a CSV or excel file incase there are over 100 animals?

Comment: @VanessaPinto . . . You can load data into SQL Server from Excel or CSV sources.  That really has nothing to do with this question, though.